# Reference for Google Earth Engine Map Screenshot

Tags: google-earth-engine, references

I would like to use a screenshot of a Landsat Image in GEE in an university paper. I read the Terms of Use but still don't really know how to put the references correctly. When the image is displayed, it only says "MapData ©2021" next to the scale. I don't think that's enough?

Example
[image]

Comment: You can read this document: https://earthengine.google.com/faq/

Comment: Thanks. However, I am still a little confused what to use for the screenshot of the image. Do I link Gorelick et al. to the image? Or "USGS/Google" as it says for the provider for the data? And do I need to show the "Map data ©2021" or not?

Comment: @xdsccc I suggest you acknowledge that you accessed Landsat imagery from the Google Earth Engine and provide a link to the GEE website in your Methods Section. If you go through the peer-reviewed literature, you will notice no more than this is done, whether the author publishes data derived from the Landsat images or shows the images themselves. You don't really need an acknowledgement in your figure caption/screenshot but, sure, you could write "source: USGS" if you want---little tedious but this seems to be encouraged in introductory GIS university courses.